# C# Sound Collision Breakout

Tags: c#, audio

So, I'm having trouble with my Breakout again. The score and lives keep going. I've tried to change it to score += or score = score+= 1, but nothing. Also, my sound keeps playing besides the times where the paddle and puck collide. I've tried putting Instance. Stop but it just keeps it from playing. I've done my research for the past two days and still haven't been able to figure out it out. Should I just make a different sound class like in [Repeating sound from one Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994292/repeating-sound-from-one-instance) ? Just asking if y'all could point me in the right direction. I know the problem lies in the segment I've included. This is in my main game.cs:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // Allows the game to exit
    if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
        this.Exit();

    paddle.Update();
    puck.Update();

    foreach (Brick brick in bricks)
    {
        brick.CheckCollision(puck);
        { score = score += 1 ; }
    }

    if (puck.OffBottom())
    {
        lives+= 1;
        if (lives == 0)
            StartGame();
    };

    puck.PaddleCollision(paddle.GetBounds());

    crashSoundInstance.Play();

    // This bottom statement I tried adding to see if it worked, but nothing...

    //  if (puck.PaddleCollision(paddle.GetBounds(false)))
    //  { crashSoundInstance.Pause(); }

    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```